# Run Java code in applet/jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I don't have very much experience at all with Applets, is there a way that I can run this code in an applet or jar file instead of having to load it in console so I can save it to another computer without Eclipse?
This program is a calculator I wrote for myself.
Thank you, I appreciate any help.
I'll be running this on a mac.

```
import java.util.*;


public class SellProfitsCalc {

    private static Scanner scan;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Stock Calculator");
        System.out.println("\n Input the Price per Share");
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double pps = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
        double c = pps * 50;
        double p = c / 10;
        double t = p / 5;
        double b = t + 21;
        double n = b + p + c;
        double e = n / 50;

        System.out.println(e);

    }

}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: When I try to run it in a Jar file, it gives me an error message saying it could not be launched

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-33.htm

Comment: I get an error saying that the jar file could not be launched whenever I try to run it after I've exported it in JAR & Runnable JAR file

Comment: You can run a jar file from console too, so it is unclear, what you're trying to say. Even an applet can exist inside an jar and an applet can be run with the appletviewer from console. What has Eclipse to do with it? You wan't to save what to another computer, the jar/the class-files?

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: *"in an applet or jar file"* Every applet these days needs to be digitally signed, and therefore must be in a Jar. So an applet will always be in a Jar, but a Jar might contain things that are not applets (e.g. a command line app., or an app. based on a `JFrame`, or an API for use on the server side..).